# jdbc connection from xml file

Tags: java, xml, jakarta-ee, jdbc

I am trying to read xml file in java.But I am facing FilenotFoundException .Could any one help?

Source Code:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
                FileInputStream fis;

                try {
                    fis = new FileInputStream("src/org/inbound/service/db/dbdetails_remedey.xml");
                    try {
                        props.loadFromXML(fis);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: src\org\inbound\service\db\dbdetails_remedy.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

Comment: The file is not there. Most likely the base folder is not the one that you expect to be.

Comment: where is the file located?

Comment: Try with the whole location like "home\<username>\<ur project name>\src\org\inbound\service\db\dbdetails_remedy.xml"

Comment: The file is located in src folder

Comment: Try using the Java 7 Paths class to display the absolute path of the file: System.out.println(Paths.get(fileLocation).toAbsolutePath()). Most likely your working directory does not contain the src folder.

Comment: The file does not exist on the relative path you have specified, Try with absolute path instead of relative path. Also check the path from the application is running and the path specified is correct from the directory

Answer (score 1):

You should load your file from your classpath. Use Object method `getClass()`;

example : `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("foo.xml")`;